# Content licensing should be made much clearer to new users

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

I recently joined this site and have been answering/asking a few questions across the network. Today I found out that all content submitted on this site is **irrevocably** licensed to the site (I believe under CC-SA, but I don't understand too much about it).

In hindsight I understand that this is necessary for the site to operate, but it should be made much clearer to new users that submitting any content here effectively makes it public forever.

Comment: Where could they have put that information that you would have bothered to read it?

Comment: B@BilltheLizard a simple hint saying "licensed under CC" and linking to the details, put underneath the input box, would work

Comment: @mEQ5aNLrK3lqs3kfSa5HbvsTWe0nIu If the content were under the public domain nobody would need to cite the author when publishing/using it.  Under the CC licence, they must cite the source, even though they will always have the right to use/publish it.

Comment: Or perhaps a link under "How to Ask". But I don't think enough people care about this. Nicol is correct that an irrevocable license on sites where you submit content is standard. Some people care about whether they can delete their content, but the licensing and TOS don't describe those rules. Those are described in the Help Center in [Why and how are some questions deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions) and [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: So far feature you requesting is "get users to read at least some guidance before asking question"... So far no one come close to solving that and I don't see any proposal here either. (Obviously as person aware of licensing concerns you've checked licensing information on the bottom of the page similar to pretty much any other site like " user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required" - so reading content on a page can't be recommendation)

Answer (score 7):

To make the license clear to new users, I propose to add a required checkbox when posting a first question or answer:

> I consent all my contributions are perpetually and irrevocably licensed under CC BY-SA 4.0 as stated in the Terms of Service.

Comment: No need for a checkbox, a note mentioning "Any content posted will be perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Overflow under CC BY-SA. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing)" should be enough I think.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Advantage of a check box is that the user is enforced to read it (otherwise people often just click on the submit button, without reading the instructions). As I propose to only show the checkbox once, requiring to check it should hurt the user experience. (Maybe for later post, adding just the note as a reminder without checkbox may be useful too).

Comment: a checkbox doesn't force people to read it any more than it not existing does.

Comment: @KevinB It does at least *encourage* them to read it. A link to a document is much easier to ignore.

Comment: @KevinB consider a typical person who wouldn't read it. What's more likely: that they leave an unexplained (because they didn't read the message) checkbox alone because they want the defaults, or that they check an unchecked box just on principle? I think the former is much more likely.

Answer (score 6):

This information is available in the help center at https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing

It's also included in the Terms of Service, which you agreed to when registering. It's your job to read it.

> [image: registration form screenshot]

Comment: And as we know, we've _all_ read the ToS. :D

Comment: I agree with @Cerbrus's slightly snarky remark here. When half of internet sites ToS is either 100 pages of legal rumbling or sometimes utter non-enforcable nonsense, a matter of "once your post receives XX points or gets an answer you can NEVER delete it again and we can display it forever" should not be hidden in ToS and a gray-on-gray text footer at the bottom of a page that already has a footer spanning half my vertical monitor size.

Comment: @OP (Please change that name...): That remark is just a joke. However, Licensing is something that's usually contained in a legal page, like the ToS. If licensing is of interest to you, you can easily find it there.

Comment: I know that licensing is usually covered in ToS, but an irrovecable grant for all submitted content should IMHO be made much clearer. (Sorry about my name, I do that on all websites - don't like the idea of people potentially googling my name and finding out everything about my online life. If it's unacceptable, I could generate a fake pseudonym and use it just for SE.)

Comment: A fake pseudonym is easier to @mention, yea.

Comment: @mEQ5aNLrK3lqs3kfSa5HbvsTWe0nIu: "*but an irrovecable grant for all submitted content should IMHO be made much clearer.*" But that's pretty much standard for collaboratively edited sites on the web. Wikipedia [licenses content with CC-SA as well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Copyrights), and they don't have a giant about it either.

Comment: @NicolBolas Just above the "save changes" button on Wikipedia edit pages: "By saving changes, you agree to the Terms of Use, and you irrevocably agree to release your contribution under the CC BY-SA 3.0 License and the GFDL. You agree that a hyperlink or URL is sufficient attribution under the Creative Commons license."

Comment: @F.George "once your post receives XX points or gets an answer you can NEVER delete it again and we can display it forever", well >10k users can see deleted answers too (and thus can share screenshots), so really it is displayed forever from the moment you post it.

Comment: When's the last time you read an EULA? I don't remember for myself.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with this. I don't think that merely linking to the Terms of Service is sufficient. In all honesty, how many people reading this Q&A actually read the Terms of Service when they registered? I'm pretty sure I didn't, and I assume that most people don't either.

Most people see EULA screens as a nuisance that rarely says anything meaningful. I recall reading about a case where a company offered people fairly substantial payment for writing to a specific address in the middle of a EULA and it took months for anybody to do so.

This agreement is non-obvious enough that users should be prominently alerted to it. This could even help prevent some instances of vandalism.

Comment: Legally you don't have a leg to stand on; EULAs and Terms of Service are required reading for anyone signing up to a service.  Not reading it because "tl;dr" doesn't mean that you're not bound by it.

Comment: @Makoto Yeah, but that doesn't change the fact that most people don't read them.

Comment: Sure, but it becomes "not the company's problem". If you don't read what you're signing up for (and the terms don't ask for something outlandish like your mortal soul), then the onus is on the account holder to understand how their rights are impacted through further use of the site and its functions.

Comment: The prompt says "it only takes a minute" and it's impossible to read the TOS in just a minute. I just tried to do so.   So the site is specifically encouraging people not to read the TOS when creating an account.

Comment: @Makoto from the company's perspective as a legal entity, sure. But what about our perspective as a community of curators?