# Post with "confidential information" repeatedly vandalized

Tags: discussion, specific-question, rollback-wars, vandalism

A post by a 5k user about a simple shell script syntax problem was asked and rapidly answered and closed as a duplicate in October.

Now, several months later, this user is replacing the question text with a simple notice that they "deleted" it for reasons of confidentiality.

There is nothing *obviously* secret in the question, though I suppose some of the variable names may communicate to an astute competitor what the OP's employer is working on. (This is by no means clear to me, but nothing else in the question is something that I could imagine would be worth keeping secret.)

I repeatedly rolled back their edits and left comments suggesting that they contact a moderator to get (only) the confidential parts properly scrubbed, but they seem to be unreceptive.

I was thinking it was better to bend the rules a bit and roll back quietly more than once in order to not produce a "[Streisand effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streisand_effect)"; but now, I am unwilling to roll back the post more times, and frankly think they deserve the attention if they persist. (I'm still not linking to the post in question, though the terminally curious can probably find it based on information in this question.)

I am reaching out to the community for guidance, and also tangentially to explain the situation in more detail to the OP. I can see three courses of action here.

- We vote to delete the post; the OP gets (roughly) what they wanted, though 10k+ users and users of the public data dump will still be able to see the post and its history, and of course it will remain visible to visitors to any site which has quietly mirrored Stack Overflow content, typically to try to steal some of the site's traffic.

  In the absence of the vandalism, this would be my preferred course of action; the problem in the question is well-covered by existing duplicates, and so the question is unlikely to be particularly useful for future visitors.
- Flag for mod attention. I imagine this actually already happened with the third rollback, but a dedicated flag with more background may be warranted.
- Escalate to public shaming in some shape or form. I think we want to avoid this.

Comment: When looking around, I only found a 5k+ user doing the same exact thing, but for a non-shell script-related post (won't post the exact tag here, but I don't think this is the same one). Just as an hint, they did that for both their own answer + their own question.

Comment: actually, I found another one with less rep but with another different flag but the same behavior. I'm guessing this should be flagged too. Is there any good flagging practice for this? or is it just "require moderator attention" and then specify the reason as "rollback-wars" or related for when content is deleted for these reasons?

Comment: I'd say we simply cast delete votes, the vandalism doesn't show good faith from the user yes, but the question itself isn't that useful given we already have better duplicates covering the same thing.

Comment: @NordineLotfi if there is already a rollback war (two rollbacks in a row), there usually is an autoflag for that. If in case you find someone to have vandalized a post but don't have edit privileges you can flag it for moderator attention. See [How do you roll back an edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271934/how-do-you-roll-back-an-edit)

Comment: Vandalism of a post is not allowed. If it's a single event roll it back and perhaps keep an eye on (but if the user redoes the vandalism it will likely be auto flagged), but if the user is performing this to many posts a moderator flag should be raised explaining the problem so they they can directly contact the user. The mod will likely also rollback the edits and lock the posts.

Comment: thank you, will do @AbdulAzizBarkat

Comment: The fact is that when they posted the content, it was licensed under CC-by-SA; the damage has likely been done. If the OP has broken some other license, then the individual who's licence they've broken should be contacting [so] about the matter.

Comment: I can speculate that they are simply embarrassed about the question and that there isn't actually anything secret in their post. I doubt that the code in question could violate anyone's copyright, as it was short and contained trivial syntax errors.

Comment: That wasnt the only post they vandalised (looks like it was only 2 though). I suspect that the problem is more that they didn't have permission to share the source code they used at the employment. The vandalism achieves little here, as all the code is still available in the history anyway. If it truly needs redaction, then the revisions need editing too.

Comment: Alright, I think I found it. They seem to be the same person that I already mentioned on my first comment here...my bad.

Comment: Mod flag it. A mod may need to inform the OP directly that their actions are not site-appropriate.

Comment: Somewhat related question: [I've rethought my question about a homework assignment—why can't I get it deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403802/12149471)

Comment: (For what it's worth, the post is gone now; it seems enough curious readers found the post and voted to delete.)

Comment: I'm sure this question here is a meta duplicate. It cannot be the first time, somebody vandalized own content (for whatever reason).

Comment: @tripleee By refusing to link to the question you're posting about you're forcing Meta users to try to find that question, based on the vaguest of breadcrumbs you've left, with the result that some of them will either not find the question, or will find an incorrect one. That means they either have no context for this post of yours, or they have incorrect context, neither of which are helpful and both of which waste their time. Meta is no different from standard SO in that questions are expected to be self-contained, and that means **not** forcing us to chase needles in haystacks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I've rethought my question about a homework assignment—why can't I get it deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403802/ive-rethought-my-question-about-a-homework-assignment-why-cant-i-get-it-delete)

Comment: Somewhat moot now, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74093928/bash-errors-and-script-if-condition (10k+)

Comment: @IanKemp The question is detailed, self-contained and clear. Does it really need a link to a particular post that triggered the question for context, and unleash the meta effect?

Comment: I'm personally glad it didn't have the link otherwise I'm sure I would have gone for a look and then joined in a pile-on. Maybe that's why I'll never be a mod :-)

Comment: @Bergi Your argument is invalid; the question was nuked from orbit long before its link was posted here. If you can figure out a way to prevent the Meta effect I'm all ears, but pretending that it can be avoided by omitting context is neither a solution nor rational.

Comment: @IanKemp The argument is that you do not need the link for anything, this is a general question, which was asked and answered without the link just fine.

Comment: Didn't deleting it kind of give them what they wanted? It seems kind of pointless, but they really should've been suspended for at least 24 hours to cool down and the post should've been locked.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine Precisely, and pretty much the reason I left out the link in the first place. Now that it's gone, I see no problem with linking to it, but having readers chase it down is what I hoped to avoid. Perhaps I should have made that more clear.

Comment: @IanKemp ^ cc on the above

Comment: They managed to cover their tracks here on SO... but it seems this was not enough :) https://devsolus.com/2022/10/17/bash-errors-and-script-if-condition/

Comment: @Cristik As predicted; but thanks for the link!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

A second rollback in quick succession already incurs an automatic "possible rollback war" flag for mods, and you can optionally add your own mod-flag to provide additional information. This is the best one can do as a regular user. How the involved user will be handled is, well, a concern for mods.

The OP's intention to get their content hidden is not in our interest. Per SO rules, every question and answer posted has been irrevocably licensed under CC-BY-SA, so it is their fault for failing to understand this file (*really?*).

*Really?* However, I just checked the Ask Question page and the Tour, neither of which mentions anything about content licensing - not even a subtle "*by submitting your question, you have read and accept [some link here]*" notice beside the Post Your Question button. It is our fault for not making this even marginally clear to users. (Might need another dedicated thread to discuss this problem.)

Comment: Related: [Content licensing should be made much clearer to new users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338214/content-licensing-should-be-made-much-clearer-to-new-users)

Comment: Thanks, I have mod-flagged and agree that the newcomer process should probably be reviewed to ensure that the licene of posted content is made clear.

Comment: "It is our fault for not making this even marginally clear to users." It's in the Terms of Use and in the [site footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTN80.png). I know hardly anybody bothers to read the ToS, but that's not our or SE's fault.

Comment: @Mast The sign saying "Beware of the Leopard" may put them off.

Comment: *"Per SO rules, every question and answer posted has been irrevocably licensed under CC-BY-SA"*. IANAL, but doesn't that only apply if you were the rights-holder in the first place? For example, if I copy an article from Wikipedia to Stack Overflow, it doesn't become CC-BY-SA. Isn't this similar? But true, it's the user their fault, and if that code shouldn't be public, I guess it's up to the employer of that user to send a request to take it down and not to the user themselves.

Comment: @g00glen00b That's correct. When posting, the post's author declares they have the right to license the content under CC BY-SA. That person can't later make an effective claim for removal based on copyright, as they have *already* declared they have the right to license the content. If the content is actually copyrighted by someone else, that other person/entity (or their legal agent) can submit a DMCA takedown notice to Stack Overflow, the company, to the prescribed notification contact, which is posted on the site (in the TOS) and registered with the US government, as required in the DMCA.

Comment: It might be possible for the intro materials to be improved. I, personally, agree that there should be an explicit, separate act to agree to the terms. *However*, the way the internet *typically* works is that such terms are *normally* placed in a Terms of Service document available on the site you're interacting with. That's normal and is the way it's done nearly *everywhere*. Users should know that they should seek out such a document, at a minimum to see how the site is expecting to interact with you. We shouldn't need to be teaching users an "internet101" course.

Comment: Note as well, @g00glen00b , that if you are copying content from another source (that might even be licensed under CC0) you would still need to adhere to *this site's* rules that proper attribution and citation is given. As such if you copy content from a site that has a less restrictive licence, a user would be able to see that in the original source that you cited .

Comment: @AndrewMorton Apologies, but we outsource to Lion-O these days. Poor guy needed the work.

Comment: I've seen some posts that definitely aren't CC-BY-SA due to being mostly GPL'd kernel quotations; generally this is allowed but it doesn't make the kernel quotations CC-BY-SA. Copyright has edges.

Comment: @Makyen By the way things happened, I'll bet copyright didn't cross the user's mind at all. Nothing we do on our side is going to make a difference.

Comment: "It is our fault ..." our in the sense of the platform service provider. I'm just a user of this platform and I'm all for telling people under which they publish content. It's kind of hidden in the terms of service and I don't like that much. But still I'm not the boss around here, so it's hardly my fault.

Comment: @Makyen A "confirm this question is public" check box should suffice, as it used to be when Teams weren't on a separate domain.

Comment: It may be difficult for new users to understand the _specific_ license details of posting, but not really if they are actually concerned about it; if one wants to know, it is not hard to find out. And aside from that, one should not expect to retain full control of their content after posting it on some random public website. Besides, "I didn't know I was agreeing to this when I signed up" doesn't fly when you have to click a box labeled "I agree to <ToS>" to sign up.

Comment: "Terms of Service document available on the site you're interacting with. That's normal and is the way it's done nearly everywhere. Users should know that they should seek out such a document, at a minimum to see how the site is expecting to interact with you." Not really, the truth is that ToS are so long and people use so many sites that expecting them to read all of them is not viable. Just following changes to ToS on websites where I signed up for is unfeasible. Though if I would be submitting code from my work I would put more effort into checking is it going to be public by default.

Answer (score 18):

> Now, several months later, this user is replacing the question text with a simple notice that they "deleted" it for reasons of confidentiality.

> There is nothing obviously secret in the question

I just wanted to point out here: There are more possible "confidentiality" reasons than the question text itself. In particular, OP might be concerned about *the [traceable] fact of having written the question*.

Either because of being ashamed of having had to ask, or because of a desire to hide an old identity (people who are trying to leave behind an old internet presence might think of all kinds of "links" to sever).

The former is IMO a bad instinct (I am an expert in Python, but I have asked several beginner level questions simply to have actually good quality reference canonicals), but it is what it is.

The latter is, of course, valid, and we should all support everyone's right to privacy. In case that is the issue, it would be a good idea to notify that OP of [How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC BY-SA?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/).

Comment: There is, of course, also the reason implied by [I've rethought my question about a homework assignment—why can't I get it deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403802).

Comment: The other reason aside from "being ashamed" could be "I don't want anyone working with me or my employer knowing I asked a question on a task I had to do at work". I don't have the right word for this, but I think ashamed isn't the right one. It depends on what the asker imagines essentially. I saw a lot of other similar instances when the asker was asking questions based on a clear corporate setting, and when one comment remarked the situation described above, they just went and tried to go on a deleting spree.

Comment: (cont): One thing to note though is, this wouldn't need to happen if they made their question into a good, out-of-context MRE (instead of copy-pasting their actual literal problem, with the company name/etc plastered everywhere).

Answer (score 15):

I looked at the question.  It currently has 0 upvotes and 4 downvotes, it’s a duplicate, pretty terribly titled, and the code sample has not been reduced to minimum, so it’s not even particularly useful as a duplicate signpost.  As such, it doesn’t seem all that valuable, and I don’t understand the insistence on keeping it.  It doesn’t seem to further the principle of building a useful knowledge base mentioned in [the general answer on deleting questions](/a/403803/3840170).  If anything, it seems to be motivated solely by spite, which in fact, [at least one person has explicitly expressed](/posts/comments/943526) (emphasis mine):

> **Didn't deleting it kind of give them what they wanted?** It seems kind of pointless, but **they really should've been suspended** for at least 24 hours to cool down and the post should've been locked.

Why is it so important *not* to give them what they wanted?  Why demand to keep the question visible and to suspend the user?  Just to make the point they are powerless?  Please.

I voted to delete.  It’s not a huge loss anyway.  Maybe we shouldn’t give askers the ability to delete *any* question they posted whatsoever, but I see no reason to refuse deletion in this particular case.  In fact, I do support [allowing deletion of negative-score questions in general](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38473/620615).

Comment: There's value beyond spite to discouraging antisocial behavior. Asking a question that others spend time answering to create a useful public resource and then withdrawing that question -- so the time spent answering no longer provides public benefit -- is something that _should_ be discouraged if we want people to be motivated to answer questions written by users whose track record of good behavior is not yet established.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy their social credit score is reduced by them having a badly-downvoted question though. That should act as discouragement.

Comment: If I recall, there might be some sort of limitation mechanism happening for users with too many deleted posts, to limit them posting more until they improve some of their previous posts.

Comment: @Cœur Too many downvoted posts (deleted or not) can lead to a posting ban. There are separate bans for asking and answering.